# Ajax call not being executed correctly after button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax, but when i press button it not work. Here is my code

```
function ftclicked() { 
      $.ajax({ 
           type: "POST",
           url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_call.php',
           data:{action:'ftclick'},
           success:function(data) {
             location.reload();
           }

      });
 }
```

Here is button code

```
<li title="Measurement Unit in feet square" onclick="ftclicked();"><span>ft&sup2;</span></li>
```

And here is ajax_call.php code

```
<?php 
if($_POST['action'] == 'ftclick') {
  set_transient( 'ts_measurement_unit_ft', "ft", 12 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    delete_transient( 'ts_measurement_unit_m' );
    return true;
}
```

Any idea why this is not working. Thanks

Comment: What means not working??? Check your console for errors...

Comment: url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax_call.php',? is it javascript file?

Comment: @A.Wolff there is no error in console i already check it.

Comment: @AadilAfzal is success callback fired?

Comment: So there is an error, check in console the network tab. You could bind error callback and see the error. I guess it's server side script which throws an error or your URL path is not relevant

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    function ftclicked() {
    formData = {
        // all your parameters here
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_call.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```